# How can I superimpose a geopandas dataframe on a raster plot?

Tags: overlay, geopandas, rasterio, plot

I have a geopandas dataframe `countries` with country polygons, and a raster dataset `raster` (read with rasterio). I've already aligned the two as follows:

```
countries = countries.to_crs(raster.crs.data)
```

I can see they're aligned when I plot each separately. However, I have been unable to display the country borders overlaid on top of the raster. The following just shows the raster image, no country borders:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from rasterio import plot as rioplot
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
base = rioplot.show(raster)
countries.plot(ax=base, color='red');
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For me it works if I pass the matplotlib `ax` object explicitly to `rasterio.plot.show`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
rasterio.plot.show(raster, ax=ax)
countries.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r');
```

Full example with raster data from naturalearth ([link](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-natural-earth-1/)) (both datasets have the same CRS, so I don't do any reprojection):

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio
import rasterio.plot

countries = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
raster = rasterio.open("NE1_50M_SR_W/NE1_50M_SR_W.tif")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
rasterio.plot.show(raster, ax=ax)
countries.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
```

gives:

[image]

For me it also does not work without passing `ax`. Not sure whether this is a bug in rasterio or geopandas.

Comment: It works! I could have sworn that this was the first thing I tried :-P

Comment: Great! And in the mean time I found the reason: the countries didn't get drawn on the figure, because rasterio did already plot it. So if you eg do `ax.get_figure()` (in your case `base.get_figure()`) to re-generated the figure, it actually has the countries plotted on them.