# Display GeoPandas on rasterio doesn't work inside loop

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, for-loop

I have written a loop that suppose to open raster from file, display it as rgb and then plot on top of it GeoPandas plot.
The problem is that the plots do not appear on to of the rasters inside the loop:

```
shapes = gpd.read_file(r'shape/shapes.shp')
shapes.dropna(subset=['geometry'],inplace=True)

...
#opening the files with the tif
files = glob.glob(str(folder_) + '/**/*.tiff', recursive=True)

for i in files:
    the_file=str(i)
    match=re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}',the_file)
    d=match.group(0)
    
    #open image
                    
    src = rasterio.open(i)
    print(src.crs)
    #create rgb visualization
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
    ax=show(src.read([4,3,2]),transform=src.transform,title=d,vmin=0,vmax=30000)
    shapes.plot(ax=ax,facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')#,color='red',legend=True)
```

the results:
[image]

no polygons on top of the image.

When I print outside the loop with `ax.get_figure()` it does plot the polygons:

[image]

but when I add it to the script I don't get the plots when I show the image:

```
    src = rasterio.open(i)
    print(src.crs)
    #create rgb visualization
    cmap = ListedColormap(['red'], name='allred')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
    ax=show(src.read([4,3,2]),transform=src.transform,title=d,vmin=0,vmax=30000)
    shapes.plot(ax=ax,facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')#,color='red',legend=True)
    ax.get_figure()
```

(result: same image with no polygons).

Why doesn't it show the polygons inside the loop? How can I solve it?

My end goal is to display the plots on top of the image inside my loop.

Comment: Does this answer from StackOverflow help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19189664/9778755

Comment: @Stefan not really, I want to plot the geopandas just like here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294072/how-can-i-superimpose-a-geopandas-dataframe-on-a-raster-plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what helped was to change the order and add `plt.show()`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
    rasterio.plot.show(src.read([4,3,2]),transform=src.transform,title=d,vmin=0,vmax=30000, ax=ax)
    shapes.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
    plt.show()
```

based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294072/how-can-i-superimpose-a-geopandas-dataframe-on-a-raster-plot).