# Displaying polygon on top of DEM with GeoPandas and Rasterio

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, matplotlib, geodataframe

I have a DEM and a polygon, both in the NAD83 Datum. I need to plot both at the same time.

Plotting the polygon

```py
import os
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as cx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import ogr2ogr

site_bdry = gpd.read_file(boundary_json)
site_bdry = site_bdry.to_crs("EPSG:26913") # NAD83 / UTM zone 13N
ax = site_bdry.plot(figsize=(10,11), alpha=0)
site_bdry.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", linewidth=2)
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs=site_bdry.crs.to_string())
```

[image]

Plotting the DEM

```py
dem = rasterio.open(dem_path)
ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.imshow(dem.read(1), cmap="Greys")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Plotting the two together like this [Plot shapefile on top of raster using plot and imshow from matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193653/plot-shapefile-on-top-of-raster-using-plot-and-imshow-from-matplotlib) and this [How can I superimpose a geopandas dataframe on a raster plot?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294072/how-can-i-superimpose-a-geopandas-dataframe-on-a-raster-plot)

```py
site_bdry = gpd.read_file(boundary_json)
site_bdry = site_bdry.to_crs("EPSG:26913")
site_bdry_buff = site_bdry["geometry"]
dem = rasterio.open(dem_path)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
plt.imshow(dem.read(1), cmap="Greys")
site_bdry.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two plotted figures. You can see that the numbers on the x-axis and y-axis are completely different. For raster the proper crs was not entered.
If your DEM's coordinates are EPSG:26913

```
from rasterio.crs import CRS    

dem = rasterio.open(dem_path, 'r+')
dem.crs = CRS.from_epsg(26913)
```

If the crs of the DEM are different, you have to go through the warp process. Find related examples.